# C# send file to ftp with user and port

Tags: c#, ftp

How can I send a file to an ftp with C# ?

The only informations I have are :

- FTP IP address
- FTP port
- FTP user

I've try this :

```
public void SendFile(string filePath)
{
    String user = "UserID";
    String IPAddr = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX";
    int port = 9999;

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, null);

        Uri address = new Uri("ftp://" + IPAddr);           
        byte[] rawResponse = client.UploadFile(address, "STOR", filePath);
        string response = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rawResponse);

        // check response
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work and it doesn't use the port (Error "unable to connect").

Comment: "it doesn't use the port". Of course not, because your code is not using the port variable.

Comment: @elgonzo indeed, I corrected port to `int`. My sentence is probably unclear, I mean something like  "How can I define a port in this connection ?"

Comment: Regarding to your edit, your code still does not use the `port` variable. It should show a warning compaining about it.

Comment: Try appending the port to the address: `Uri address = new Uri("ftp://" + IPAddr + ":" + port.ToString());` I've never done that, but seems like it should work.

Comment: Yeah, i guess Nisarg is right. It seems, when using WebClient, the ftp port has to be part of the URI string. Also, in case of connection problems always test with another reliable(!) ftp client (such as FileZilla, for example) to determine whether the problem is caused by the network/server or by something in your code...

Comment: use `FtpWebRequest`. It's simple. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Nisarg first I've try to set `address.Port` but it's read only. With your code the `address.Port` changes. The file is still not send but it does not work with FileZilla, I'll contact the administrator.

Comment: @A.Pissicat If it is indeed an issue from the FTP server, you can delete the question. Else you've got the answer, I hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was undefined port. To set the port, just do :

```
 Uri address = new Uri($"ftp://{IPAddr}:{port}");           
 byte[] rawResponse = client.UploadFile(address, "STOR", filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify port in the address if you use an `FtpWebRequest` this is what i use and it works with specific port.

```
internal class FTPManager
{
    private const string FTPAddress = "ftp://www.example.com:9211/";
    private const string Username = "Yummy";
    private const string Password = "Nachos";

    public byte[] DownloadFile(string relativePath)
    {
        var fileData = new byte[0];

        try
        {
            // parse the path
            relativePath = ParseRelativePath(relativePath);

            using (var request = new WebClient())
            {
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
                fileData = request.DownloadData(FTPAddress + relativePath);
            }

        }
        catch { }

        return fileData;
    }

    public bool DoesFileExist(string relativePath)
    {
        var fileExist = false;

        var request = WebRequest.Create(FTPAddress + ParseRelativePath(relativePath));
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);

        try
        {
            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                fileExist = true;
            }
        }
        catch { }

        return fileExist;
    }

    // upload file and handle everything
    public void UploadFile(string relativePath, byte[] fileBinary)
    {
        // parse the path
        relativePath = ParseRelativePath(relativePath);

        // create the folder before writing the file
        CreateFolders(relativePath);

        // delete the file
        DeleteFile(relativePath);

        // upload the file
        SendFile(relativePath, fileBinary);
    }

    private void SendFile(string relativePath, byte[] fileBinary)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(FTPAddress + relativePath);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
            var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
            var sourceStream = new MemoryStream(fileBinary);
            var length = 1024;
            var buffer = new byte[length];
            var bytesRead = 0;

            do
            {
                bytesRead = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, length);
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            } while (bytesRead != 0);

            sourceStream.Close();
            stream.Close();
        }
        catch 
        {

        }
    }

    private void DeleteFile(string relativePath)
    {
        try
        {
            WebRequest ftpRequest = WebRequest.Create(FTPAddress + relativePath);
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
            ftpRequest.GetResponse();
        }
        catch { }
    }

    // parse the relative path for strange slashes
    private string ParseRelativePath(string relativePath)
    {
        // split to remove all slashes and duplicates
        var split = relativePath.Split(new string[] { "\\", "/" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // join the string back with valid slash
        var result = String.Join("/", split);

        return result;
    }

    // Check if the relative path need folders to be created
    private void CreateFolders(string relativePath)
    {
        if (relativePath.IndexOf("/") > 0)
        {
            var folders = relativePath.Split(new[] { "/" }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();

            var folderToCreate = FTPAddress.Substring(0, FTPAddress.Length - 1);

            for (int i = 0; i < folders.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                folderToCreate += ("/" + folders[i]);

                CreateFolder(folderToCreate);
            }
        }
    }

    // create a single folder on the FTP
    private void CreateFolder(string folderPath)
    {
        try
        {
            WebRequest ftpRequest = WebRequest.Create(folderPath);
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
            ftpRequest.GetResponse();
        }
        catch { } // create folder will fail if it already exist
    }
}
```